# How to get the file name from the intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

This is my manifest file. After using intent filter i download the ics file from the mail attachment. When i open the downloaded file it start my application. I need to get the file name and data of the selected file in my application. What should i do in the manifest and the java file. I am very new to android can any one help me????

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icsicon">
    <activity android:name=".setMIMEfile" android:label="@string/app_name">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ics" />    
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();                
String name = intent.getData().getPath();
```

String name will contain your selected file path, from that path you can read your file

Comment: What should I do in the manifest to receive files of all types?

Answer (score 13):

Note that

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getData().getEncodedPath();
```

gives you an encoded string, e.g. a space in the file name is encoded as "%20". If you want to open the file, you have to use

```
intent.getData().getPath()
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getData().getLastPathSegment();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file name using intent.getData().

Comment: how to give user permissions to access the file in mainfeast ?
and how to get the file name

Comment: Thank you for your response.I got the file path