# How to get file path from Intent Filter (email attachment/download)

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have defined the following Intent filter in my manifest which allows me to open .ips files that are downloaded from the browser and also from email attachments.

```
<intent-filter
                android:icon='@drawable/ic_launcher'
                android:label="@string/quick_patcher_label"
                android:priority='1'>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern="*.ips" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="http" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.ips" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="https" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.ips" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I tried part of the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656987/android-intent-filter-custom-filetype) which resulted in "false" as the file name, and I tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971871/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-the-intent) too. How can I retrieve the file path of the file I've opened with this intent filter from within my activity?

EDIT: Found this in another question, it works when opening from downloads but gives a NullPointerException for opening from emails. Anyone know why that is?

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I retrieve the file path of the file I've opened with this intent filter from within my activity?

There might not *be* a "file path". You use `getIntent().getData()` to get the `Uri` of the data. Then, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` for the data from that `Uri`.

Comment: I see, is there a chance you can edit your answer with a code example? thanks

Comment: Well say I did that and got an InputStream, how do I then get the file path?

Comment: @Linkandzelda: You don't get the file path, as there isn't a file path. You use the `InputStream` to get at the data. If you can only work with file paths, restrict your app to the `file` scheme.

Comment: So you're saying that a file I downloaded onto my device from the web browser doesn't have a file path?

Comment: @Linkandzelda: It may or may not, and even if it does, you may or may not have access to that file path. You are guaranteed access to the `Uri` (otherwise, the app invoking yours is broken). But that could easily be a `content://` `Uri`, where the `ContentProvider` is serving data out of a file on internal storage (inaccessible to you), from a database `BLOB` column (not a file), from an asset (not a file), etc. Write your app to only deal with the `Uri` and resulting `InputStream`.

Comment: I don't think I can make my app use an InputStream, for now If you check my question again I found a solution to opening the downloads but not the email attachment.

Comment: @Linkandzelda: Your results prove my point. If your app cannot use an `InputStream`, then restrict yourself to the `file` scheme. This will not help you with email attachments, which are not accessible as files to you, but it will more correctly limit you to `Uri` values that you can possibly handle.

Comment: Ok, I understand your answer now, looks like I'll have to restrict it. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried to restrict to file scheme and it seems email and opening from downloads is both part of content scheme. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

From emails, you are probably getting EXTRA_TEXT and not a STREAM. So the STREAM comes out null.

Emails never exist as a file. You can save them to a file. But then they are no longer an email.

So, next time you are asked: "When is an email not an email?", you will know the answer and the asker will bow to your superior wisdom and ask to be your disciple. But I digress...